# How to show REST API error message in the B2C login form

Tags: azure, azure-ad-b2c, identity-experience-framework

I have a multiple applications that use the same custom policy to authenticate user. In TrustFrameworkExtensions I defined two claims provider, one for local account and one for  user of my company AD tenant (social account) , I have also a claims provider for retrieve custom attributes and for check if the user is enabled for the caller application, this claims provider is configured in user jorney like a orchestration step before the JWT token is created.
The API Application return claims with custom attributes if the user is enabled and return a response with HttpStatusCode.Conflict and error message if not.
How can show the error message in the login form before it back to the calling application?
PS: I have a custom UI login form

**UPDATE**

I found a right technical profile  "SelfAsserted-LocalAccountSignin" and now works ! But I have 2 more questions.
1. In my api application, in input claims, extension property are missing , I think it's because the user not logged yet, is it possible obtain all claims ? If this isn't possibile I must read data in my api with Graph 
by signinName.
2. My login form allows authentication as a local user and as a user of my company AD tenant (social account). 
The ValidationTechnicalProfiles in "SelfAsserted-LocalAccountSignin"
works with local user only, I tried to configure a ValidationTechnicalProfiles for "SM-SocialLogin" TechnicalProfile but doesn't work

Comment: AFAIK to show errors you need to use the technical profile as a validation technical profile instead of a claims exchange.

Comment: I tried to use the technical profile but it doesn't work, probably my configuration is wrong. Can you tell me where I can find an example ?
All the ones I found and tried worked with the registration form, not with the login form.

In my ClaimsProvider I defined this TecnicalProfile

<TechnicalProfile Id="SelfAsserted-LocalAccountSignin-Email">
      <ValidationTechnicalProfiles>
        <ValidationTechnicalProfile ReferenceId="CheckSignIn" />
      </ValidationTechnicalProfiles>
    </TechnicalProfile>